# High side mosfet 12V switch from isolated 3V3 GPIO

Tags: mosfet, stm32, opto-isolator

I want to switch power of 12V laser sensor from 3V3 [STM32H753VI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753vi.html) GPIO. I will power on or off for long time (It's not PWM here) I am not comfortable with Mosfet and Optocoupler so I need help to be sure I can route this to my board. I want to go high side because the sensor laser set 12V to output when I cut the ground. I need to be isolated because of isolated power supply.

---

### SCHEMATIC

[image: SCH]
Laser power is connected to CN1 and draw about 100mA and can work between 10V to 14V.
The [STM32H753VI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753vi.html) work at 3V3 and GPIO will be set as open drain.
I want to use [EL3H7-G](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/143/EL3H7-G-598448.pdf) (C) Optocoupler and [STR2P3LLH6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/96/4a/55/9d/3c/16/47/d6/DM00084050.pdf/files/DM00084050.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00084050.pdf) Mosfet because of small footprint.

---

### DRIVING OPTOCOUPLER

When GPIO is shorted to ground current flow to [EL3H7-G](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/143/EL3H7-G-598448.pdf) led, I get forward voltage from sheet (page 3) and curve (page 4)

[image: Forward Voltage]
[image: Forward voltage curve]

GPIO could not handle more than 20mA to the GPIO so I will set **If=10mA**
R1=(3.3V-1.2V)/0.01A=210ohms

I will go with **R1=200ohms**
If=(3.3V-1.2V)/200=10.5mA

---

### OPTOCOUPLER Ic CURRENT

I want to When I look into [EL3H7-G](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/143/EL3H7-G-598448.pdf) datasheet (page 3) I can see optocoupler transistor can be saturated with If=10mA and Ic=1ma so Vce(sat) will be at 0.2V max .
(On the curve I can see I can go to 6ma into saturated region)

[image: VCEsat]
[image: VCE curve]

R2=(12V-0.2V)/0.001=11.8kOhms
I will go with **R2=10kOhms**
Ic=(12V-0.2V)/10000ohms=1.18mA
**Ic=1.18mA**

---

### MOSFET Vgs

Vgs is -R2 voltage
VR2=12V-0.2V=11.8V
**Vgs=-11.8V**

From [STR2P3LLH6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/96/4a/55/9d/3c/16/47/d6/DM00084050.pdf/files/DM00084050.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00084050.pdf) datasheet (page 3) I can see **Vgs(th)=-2.5V**

[image: Vgs(th)]

Vgs (-11.8V) is more lower than Vgs(th) (-2.5V) so **Mosfet will turn On.**

[image: Vgs max]

I can see on [STR2P3LLH6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/96/4a/55/9d/3c/16/47/d6/DM00084050.pdf/files/DM00084050.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00084050.pdf) datasheet (page 2) Vgs max is +/-20V
so **I will probably not destroy the gate with -11.8V**

---

### OUTPUT (VPWR)

On [STR2P3LLH6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/96/4a/55/9d/3c/16/47/d6/DM00084050.pdf/files/DM00084050.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00084050.pdf) datasheet (page 5) I can see the Rdson is about 48mOhms for 100mA

[image: Vgs(th)]
[image: Rdson]

Vds=-(0.048ohms*0.1A)=-4.8mV

VPWR=12V-0.0048V=11.99V
**VPWR=11.99V**

I can now compute Mosfet dissipated power

P=0.0048V*0.1A=480µW
**P=480µW**

**P (480µW) is really lower than Ptot (0.35W)**

---

### CONCLUSION

- Do you think Mosfet will fully On or Off as I want ?
- Do you think I will destroy the Mosfet, Optocoupler or STM32 ?
- Do you think optocoupler and Mosfet are about a good choice ?
- Do you think It's good to add small value R3 between collector and gate ?

[image: R3]

Thanks in advance for your help

***Edit 2021-06-24***
I implement this design but got an [Always On Problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572703/high-side-mosfet-12v-switch-from-isolated-3v3-gpio-always-on) here

***Edit 2022-02-04***
My problem [Always On Problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572703/high-side-mosfet-12v-switch-from-isolated-3v3-gpio-always-on) came from my PCB and not from schematic and method here, you can use it without problem, as soon as you respect you MOSFET footprint :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This design has a very high margin with good choices for On/Off margin.

With 10:1 CTR on the design or 10% output and is well exceeded by guaranteed CTR.

- Keep in mind Vce loses gain when saturated and rises above 0.5V quickly to 1V at which point the worst-case FET leakage is guaranteed to be Id=-250 nA max where it is possible that 2mA LED drive "could" work to turn on.
- The Ron is 56 mohm max at Vgs= - 10 and a little bit less at -12V.  Your load is equivalent to 12V/0.1A = 120 Ohms so a switch resistance ratio of 1% max is desirable so 0.056/120  or overkill but fine.
- Rg is redundant with Rce equivalent resistance Vce(sat)/Ic = 0.2V/1.18mA = 169 ohm approx.

Good job.

Comment: Big THANKS to take time for your response, and lot of tips about switching resistance. I will take look of leakage because I don't take it into account.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes.
2. No.  And, you could reduce the optocoupler LED current to 5 mA for even more operating margin.
3. Yes.
4. Not needed in any way, but won't hurt anything or affect the circuit's overall performance.

A resistor is placed in series with the gate to dampen unwanted oscillations that occur when large power MOSFETs (with a very large gate capacitance) are driven with a very fast risetime signal, which is common in switching power supplies.  The gate capacitance and wiring inductance form a tank circuit that can ring at many times the switching frequency, causing a ton of compliance headaches.  None of that applies here.

5. **O.U.T.S.T.A.N.D.I.N.G** question presentation.

Comment: Many thanks to take time to help me., thanks for tips about R3 and gate capacitance

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you may want to consider changing the optoisolator for another type of galvanic isolation technique such as capacitive or inductive which uses less power.

Texas Instruments has a great series of videos on the subject of [galvanic isolation](https://training.ti.com/ti-precision-labs-isolation-what-galvanic-isolation) which discusses inductive, capacitive and optical isolation techniques.

For example, here's the [data sheet for the Silicon Labs Si823Hx](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si823Hx-DataSheet.pdf) which is an isolated gate driver in one chip.

It could look something like this:

[image: Si823H9 Isolated Gate Driver]

Comment: Thank you for this information, this king of chip seam to be the Holy Grail I search without success before going to optocoupler/mosfet chain. For the next project I think I will consider more deeply this kind of solution but for now I'm in hurry I need to route by board befire the deadline but this seem to be THE modern solution.

Comment: And I forgot to say thank for the really interesting video, I need to review more time thoses explained concepts

Comment: Just an aside: These types of isolators are great, but the big drawback is usually that they cost 10X what a simple optocoupler costs in volume.  So it's technically a great solution, but if cost is an issue it might not be an economically great solution.

Comment: @JohnD thank you for pointing this, effectively this is the order of magnitude, for example EL3H7(C)(TA)-VG is 0.45€ and SI823H9AD-IS4 is 2.95€

Comment: If you ever need reliable multichannel (8 channels or connect them together for higher current capability) high side switching, check ISO8200B from ST. They have build-in protection for all cases (ESD, over-current, over-temperature, short circuit, over-voltage, loss of ground...) and they will survive everything! They may cost more (~5 Euro for 8 Channels), but I can sleep at night knowing my outputs will be the last thing that fails, no matter what.